# Inserting events in to google calendar using gives an error 404 "NOT FOUND"

Tags: node.js, express, google-calendar-api

I am creating a Node JS (Express) web app that will display a user's Google Calendar events, once they have logged in and insert events events into google calendar from my database.

I am trying to insert events via the Google Calendar API with a service account

Code I used :

```
var   googleapis = require("googleapis"),
    googleCal = googleapis.calendar("v3"),
    serviceEmail = "*****@*******gserviceaccount.com",
    serviceKeyFile = "./key.p12";

var authClient = new googleapis.auth.JWT(
        serviceEmail,
        serviceKeyFile,
        null,
        ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
    );

authClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
  console.log("tokens"+JSON.stringify(tokens));
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        googleCal.events.list({
            auth: authClient,
            calendarId: "*********@gmail.com",
            fields: {
                items: ["end","start","summary"]
            }
        }, function (err, CL) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("calendar"+CL);
            }
        });
    }
})
var event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2017-07-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2017-07-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees': [
    {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
    {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'},
  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': false,
    'overrides': [
      {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
      {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
    ],
  },
};
googleCal.events.insert({
    auth: authClient,
    calendarId:'primary',
     resource: event,
}, function (err, events) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("there is an error"+err);
    } else {
        console.log(events);
        console.log("events are created successfully");
    }
})
```

My problem is while executing it is displaying an error like

> { Error: Not Found
>       at Request._callback (D:\studentportal\node_modules\google-auth-library\lib\transporters.js:85:15)
>       at Request.self.callback (D:\studentportal\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at Request. (D:\studentportal\node_modules\request\request.js:1081:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (D:\studentportal\node_modules\request\request.js:1001:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:291:16)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)   code: 404,   errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'notFound',
>   message: 'Not Found' } ] }

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this and hopefully it helps you [Handle API Error: 404](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#404_not_found)

> 404: Not Found
>
> The specified resource was not found. This can happen in several
>   cases. Here are some examples:
>
> when the requested resource (with the provided ID) has never existed
>   when accessing a calendar that the user can not access

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```